# Connection string in usercontrol not working

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, user-controls, connection-string

I was trying(learning) to make UserControl in Winforms.Here goes my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LoginTestDB_cf"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=LoginTestDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I made a static class and tried to get the connection string. Thats how I tried:

```
static class Helper
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginTestDB_cf"].ConnectionString;
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to access the connection string like this:

```
_myCommand = "my_command_text";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = Helper.ConnectionString; //getting error
_cmd = new SqlCommand(_myCommand, con);
con.Open();
```

Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I am getting the error in setting the connection string. May i know what's wrong here? I am sure there is a small error or ignorance playing the dirty part, but not able to recognize that.

In helper class, i have even tried with

```
string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginTestDB_cf"].ToString();
```

But still no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint in the ConnectionString property of Helper class and inspecting the ConnectionStrings property of the Configuration Manager?

Comment: You code seems right, Initially I thought you might of misspelled the connection name...

Comment: string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginTestDB_cf"].ConnectionString; // giving error at this code...

Comment: is it because of I am doing it in Usercontrol??

Comment: How many projects do you have and where are those files? The app.config should be in the project that generates the exe, not in a class library that generates a dll.

Comment: yes...i have it in project...let me upload the solution

Comment: sorry...i think these IT folks wont allow me to access rapidshare or any other site of that kind. but i have access to mails however. Thanks

Comment: and if you remove the underscore from both the app.config and the code? ps. the appsettings is not going to work (unless you also changed the config file). do you have other code that access the app.config which does work?

Comment: No, nothing is accessing app.onfig

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i came up with a solution and hoping desperatly that someone prove me wrong. I copied the same files (add existing items) to a different Winforms(windowsFormApplication) solution. And volla!! everything worked fine. So for now, I am thinkng that, connection strings cannot be used in UserControl, even though I cannot justify for what I am saying. But yes, I have used the same files of the project and same content of app.config (of course I changed the namespace name for files) and everything worked great. Please let me know if I am getting basics wrong. surely i will continue to serach on internet for this problem. Thank you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the connection string in your newly created control.

Here's my setup:

[image]

**User control** is a single button with attached code that you provided. Helper class is a part of the user control. As you can see I stepped through it just fine to the open line past where you were encountering your problem. (It opens and then closes the connection just fine, I checked).

Comment: are custom controls are same as usercontrol??i think no. well, have you tried the same thing with UserControl??

Comment: You can see in the SS that that code is part of a usercontrol. Public partial class usercontrol : usercontrol. Actually if you look at the tab name: UserControl.

Comment: but foe some unknown reason, its not working for me.let me see. will post the update

Comment: Any luck with the project I put together for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved, in my case! In reality the fact is that being in a usercontrol alters slightly the inserted Connectionstring! The solution is just reverting this little changes by using the method Replace like in any other string! To find the difference, just let the connectionstring being inserted in some panel or textbox and then compare it with the correct one opening the html of the online version of the page.
Of course you have first to disable all the things which require the connection to the online database!